# How to load Ajax driven data after user clicks browser Back Button

Tags: ajax, button, coldfusion, back

We have a website product that allows users to search rental inventory, view results and then click through to a details page.

On the results page, we also allow users the option to refine their search via bedrooms, bathrooms, price, etc. When the form changes, we do not reload the page, we use Ajax to run a new search query and load the new results into the container.

For example, when the user first did a search, they got back 100 properties. Then they refine their search for 3 bed, 5 bathrooms, view = oceanfront and they get back 10 properties.  Once the user finds a property they like, they typically click through to the details page. But, let's say they change their mind and click the browser 'back button'.

When that happens, all of our search params that were loaded via Ajax are now gone and our property count is back to 100 instead of 10.

So what I have realized is any data loaded via Ajax is not being cached in the browser so the original search is loaded not the refined search.

After doing some research, I think using history.pushState() and history.popstate() might be the solution but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to implement it for our problem.

Is there a better solution? If not, will history.pushState() work?

Comment: It might, give it a shot.

Comment: This sort of worked initially, but as I started going back and forth between my two pages I started getting wonky results:   var myformdata = $('#myform').serialize();  history.pushState(myformdata,null,null);    This script is fired every time the form is submitted via Ajax

Comment: well, the idea would be to update the url too when you use pushState, essentially making your search results deep linkable.

Comment: Hmm...the results page is always the same, results.cfm...does that make a difference?   Also, when I click through to the detail page, should I also call history.pushstate and pass in the new URL?